# Vectorizing a function that takes multidimensional input over a multidimensional array in JAX

Tags: python, arrays, jax

I have been trying to vectorize a function that takes two 2D arrays and return a
2D array of the same shape, so that I can apply it element wise to two 4D arrays.
Here is an example:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import map

M = jnp.arange(0, 400).reshape((10, 10, 2, 2))
N = jnp.arange(400, 800).reshape((10, 10, 2, 2))

def func(A, B):
    return jnp.dot(A, B)

R = vmap(func, in_axes=(1, 1))(M, N)
print(R.shape) #(10, 10, 2, 10, 2)
```

`func` is the function that I would like to apply to the 2x2 matrices that are contained in `M` and `N`. I expected the result to be of the shape `(10, 10, 2, 2)` because I thought that `vmap` applies the function to each subarray of the specified axis. Clearly I am not correctly understanding how it works. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`vmap` will map over a single axis at a time. Since you want to map over two axes in each array, you should use two `vmap` calls:

```py
R = vmap(vmap(func))(M, N)
print(R.shape) #(10, 10, 2, 2)
```

The reason a single `vmap` returns the shape it does is because you're mapping over a single axis of each array, so that the inputs to `func` effectively have shapes `(10, 2, 2)` and `(10, 2, 2)`. If you call `jnp.dot` on arrays of these shapes, it will return an array of shape `(10, 2, 10, 2)` (the [`jnp.dot` documentation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.dot.html) makes clear why this is); adding the leading mapped dimension of size `(10,)` results in the shape you saw originally.

Comment: how about the case where the number of dimensions before the 2x2 is varying? Stacking vmaps gets inconvenient real quick

Comment: In that case vmap is probably not the right tool. For example, in the case of the function above, you could construct a flexibly-batched version using [`jnp.einsum`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.einsum.html) instead: `func = lambda M, N: jnp.einsum("...ij,...jk->...ik", M, N)`. For more general functions, [`jnp.vectorize`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.vectorize.html) might be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jax.numpy.einsum` too. This would allow you to cooperate with changing dimensions of `M` and `N`. Here is an example of 5 dimensional `M` and `N`:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import vmap
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

M = jnp.arange(0, 4000).reshape((10, 10, 10, 2, 2))
N = jnp.arange(4000, 8000).reshape((10, 10, 10, 2, 2))

C = letters[:(M.ndim - 2)] # You will map over first M.ndim-2 dimensions
subscripts = C+'XY,'+C+'YZ->'+C+'XZ' # Here I create the einsum script for the product

R1 = jnp.einsum(subscripts, M, N)
```

You could do the same thing with `vmap`. But you need three `vmap` calls this time:

```
def func(A, B):
    return jnp.dot(A, B)

R2 = vmap(vmap(vmap(func)))(M, N)

assert jnp.allclose(R1, R2)
```